# Oracle - select one field into multiple variables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a question that does not give me sleep.
How can I select one field and put in multiple variables in Oracle.
Example:

```
declare
   v_num_1 number;
   v_num_2 number;
   v_num_3 number;
begin
   select 123 into v_num_1, v_num_2, v_num_3
   from dual;
end;
```

This code is obviously incorrect - I give an error about too many variables.
However, I wonder if it exist another way to put in one value into multiple variables?

I will be very grateful for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just repeat the `123`:

```
declare
   v_num_1 number;
   v_num_2 number;
   v_num_3 number;
begin
   select 123, 123, 123 into v_num_1, v_num_2, v_num_3
   from dual;
end;
```

Or use simple assignment:

```
declare
   v_num_1 number;
   v_num_2 number;
   v_num_3 number;
begin
   v_num_1 := 123;
   v_num_2 := 123;
   v_num_3 := 123;
end;
```